# Conversión correcta de dato en Float-Bigint en cadena de text SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estimad@s, buenos días, acudo a ustedes para entender algo de la conversión de un tipo de datos a otro. Actualmente, donde trabajo tiene `SQL 2008` sino me equivoco, por lo que no puedo usar diferentes funciones como `FORMAT`, etc. Otro aspecto a tener en cuenta es que yo no hice el diseño de las tablas, no se quién las hizo ni sé porque las hizo así. Pero, usa tipo de datos en campos que para mi no deberían ser así. Por ejemplo, para el campo S el tipo de dato es `FLOAT` lo cual no debería ser así (según yo) porque es un campo de números enteros. Fuera de estas cosas que me hacen ruido, consulto lo siguiente, para un campo cuyo tipo de dato es `FLOAT` ¿Cuál es la forma recomendada de castearlo a `NVARCHAR` o una cadena de caracteres?

```
DECLARE @T1 FLOAT = 99061
DECLARE @T2 FLOAT = 128000

SELECT S
INTO #TempoCodFila
FROM C
WHERE T IN (@T1, @T2) AND CU = 1


SELECT STR(S, 15,0) 'STR', TRY_CAST(S AS NVARCHAR) 'TRY', CONVERT(NVARCHAR, S) 'CONVERT', CAST(S AS NVARCHAR(15)) 'CAST', S'ORIGINAL'
FROM #TempoCF

DROP TABLE #TempoCF
```

Esto me devuelve:

```
  STR           TRY            CONVERT          CAST        ORIGINAL
27772483    2.77725e+007    2.77725e+007    2.77725e+007    27772483
34241409    3.42414e+007    3.42414e+007    3.42414e+007    34241409
```

¿Alguien puede explicarme porque a excepción del STR los demás tipos de conversiones generan un exponencial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es probable que tengas razón al decir que alguien cometió un error al definir un campo de enteros como float. El tipo de dato `float` es un tipo de dato aproximado y se maneja en notación científica. Es por eso que al convertirlo directamente a una cadena, eso es lo que vemos. Aunque con la longitud adecuada, se alcanza a ver como un número natural en la conversión por default.

Si queremos que se muestre como número natural en longitudes mayores, tenemos que tomar un paso intermedio y convertirlo en un tipo de dato numérico exacto como bigint o decimal. Por cierto, si solo vas a convertir números no necesitas usar nvarchar, pero sí es bueno que acostumbres a asignar longitudes a las cadenas.

Dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo y de paso ves la diferencia entre usar el doble `CONVERT()` y usar `STR().

```
SELECT  S                                                   AS [ORIGINAL],
        STR(S, 20,0)                                        AS [STR], 
        TRY_CONVERT( VARCHAR(20), TRY_CONVERT( bigint, S))  AS [TRY_CONVERT], 
        TRY_CAST(S AS NVARCHAR)                             AS [TRY_CAST], 
        CAST(S AS NVARCHAR(15))                             AS [CAST]
FROM (VALUES(CAST( 12345678901234567890 AS float)),
            (CAST( 1234567890123456789 AS float)),
            (CAST( 123456789012345678 AS float)),
            (CAST( 12345678901234567 AS float)),
            (CAST( 1234567890123456 AS float)),
            (CAST( 123456789012345 AS float)),
            (CAST( 12345678901234 AS float)),
            (CAST( 1234567890123 AS float)),
            (CAST( 123456789012 AS float)),
            (CAST( 12345678901 AS float)),
            (CAST( 1234567890 AS float)),
            (CAST( 123456789 AS float)),
            (CAST( 12345678 AS float)),
            (CAST( 1234567 AS float)),
            (CAST( 123456 AS float)),
            (CAST( 12345 AS float)),
            (CAST( 1234 AS float)),
            (CAST( 123 AS float)),
            (CAST( 12 AS float)),
            (CAST( 1 AS float)))x(S);
```

Resultado:

```
ORIGINAL               STR                  TRY_CONVERT           TRY_CAST                       CAST
---------------------- -------------------- --------------------- ------------------------------ ---------------
1.23456789012346E+19   12345678901234567000 NULL                  1.23457e+019                   1.23457e+019
1.23456789012346E+18    1234567890123456800 1234567890123456768   1.23457e+018                   1.23457e+018
1.23456789012346E+17     123456789012345680 123456789012345680    1.23457e+017                   1.23457e+017
1.23456789012346E+16      12345678901234568 12345678901234568     1.23457e+016                   1.23457e+016
1.23456789012346E+15       1234567890123456 1234567890123456      1.23457e+015                   1.23457e+015
123456789012345             123456789012345 123456789012345       1.23457e+014                   1.23457e+014
12345678901234               12345678901234 12345678901234        1.23457e+013                   1.23457e+013
1234567890123                 1234567890123 1234567890123         1.23457e+012                   1.23457e+012
123456789012                   123456789012 123456789012          1.23457e+011                   1.23457e+011
12345678901                     12345678901 12345678901           1.23457e+010                   1.23457e+010
1234567890                       1234567890 1234567890            1.23457e+009                   1.23457e+009
123456789                         123456789 123456789             1.23457e+008                   1.23457e+008
12345678                           12345678 12345678              1.23457e+007                   1.23457e+007
1234567                             1234567 1234567               1.23457e+006                   1.23457e+006
123456                               123456 123456                123456                         123456
12345                                 12345 12345                 12345                          12345
1234                                   1234 1234                  1234                           1234
123                                     123 123                   123                            123
12                                       12 12                    12                             12
1                                         1 1                     1                              1
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación!